# JDK 8 (remove odbc jdbc driver) so how to link with MS access?

Tags: java-8

When use `netbeans7.4` with `JDK 8` (remove odbc jdbc driver)
so how to link with `MS access` ??

When use method in previous version of `jdk`, catch this error

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`

So how write driver and url in jdk8??

Comment: UCanAccess seems to be working quite OK: http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver Exception occuring ? why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984438/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-sun-jdbc-odbc-jdbcodbcdriver-exception-occurin)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc)

Comment: You can use jdbc odbc classes from jre7 also in jre8 - see stackoverflow.com/a/34617075/2110961